# A function evaluated at a operator

Tags: linear-algebra

If dim$(V)=n$ and $\tau \in \mathcal {L}(V)$, prove that there is a nonzero polynomial $p(x)\in F[x]$ for which $p(\tau)=0$. I don't understand how come a function can be evaluated at a linear operator $\tau$.

Comment: A polynomial is not a function. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, how to evaluate a polynomial $p(x) \in F[x]$ at a linear operator $\tau \in \mathcal L(V)$?  The first thing to realize is that powers of $\tau$ make sense as elements of $\mathcal L(V)$; e.g., for

$\vec v \in V, \tag 1$ we have

$\tau \vec v \in V, \tag 2$

so it makes sense to take

$\tau^2 \vec v = \tau(\tau \vec v); \tag 3$

indeed, accepting (3), we may inductively define

$\tau^{k + 1} \vec v = \tau (\tau^k\vec v); \tag 4$

thus we define $\tau^m$ for any $m \in \Bbb N$; if $\tau$ is represented by a matrix

$[\tau_{ij}], \tag 5$

then it is easy to see that $\tau^m$ is represented by the matrix

$[(\tau^m)_{ij}] = [\tau_{ij}]^m. \tag 6$

In any event, given $\tau^m$, we see that

$(\alpha \tau^m)(\vec v) = \alpha (\tau^m \vec v); \tag 7$

and we may also construct and evaluate expressions such as

$(\alpha \tau^l + \beta \tau^m)\vec v =  \alpha \tau^l \vec v + \beta \tau^m \vec v \tag 8$

using the ordinary linearity properties of $\mathcal L(V)$; continuing in this vein, we can for

$p(x) \in F[x], \; p(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^m p_i x^i, \tag 9$

meaningfully define

$p(\tau) = \displaystyle \sum_0^m p_i \tau^i \in \mathcal L(V), \tag{10}$

which is the general formula for $p(\tau)$.

Now we recall that

$\dim_F \mathcal L(V) = n^2; \tag{11}$

thus the set

$\{I, \tau, \tau^2, \ldots, \tau^{n - 1}, \tau^{n^2 - 1}, \tau^{n^2} \} \subset \mathcal L(V), \tag{12}$

having as it does $n^2 + 1$ elements, must be linearly dependent over $F$; hence we may find $n^2 +1$ members

$c_i \in F,  \tag{13}$

not all $0$, such that

$\displaystyle \sum_0^{n^2} c_i \tau_i = 0; \tag{14}$

$\tau$ then satisfies the polynomial

$c(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{n^2} c_i x^i \in F[x]. \tag{14}$

We have shown that every $\tau \in F[x]$ satisfies a polynomial of degree at most $n^2$, but this is far from optimal.   For example, the well-known Cayley-Hamilton theorem shows that $\tau$ obeys a degree-$n$ polynomial; but the proof of that result is somewhat more involved than what we have done here, and hence will be saved for yet another post.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is also a finite dimensional vector space (over what?) Thus, you can find some integer $m$ (you can even explicitly find $m$ in terms of $n$) such that:
$$\{1,\tau, \tau^2,\dots \tau^m\}$$ are linearly dependent. I think you can continue from here.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a function, it's a polynomial. For polynomials, it's easy to understand:
if the polynomial is $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n$, and the operator is $\tau$,
then $f(\tau) = a_0 I + a_1 \tau + \ldots + a_n \tau^n$.
This works in any algebra over a field $F$, where the polynomial has coefficients in $F$.

Comment: Note that in this context, the powers of $x$ are evaluated by repeated composition of $\tau$ with itself, while the coefficients of the polynomial are treated as scalar multiples of those powers.  Finally the terms of the polynomial are added together as one adds linear mappings to get a linear mapping as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be the characterstic Polynomial of $\tau$. Then there exist $a_0,a_1,\cdots a_{n-1}\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\det(\tau-\lambda I)=p(t)=a_0+a_1 t+\cdots a_{n-1}t^{n-1}=0$. Plugging $\tau$ yeilds
$p(\tau)=0$